# What is the earliest supported date in moment.js and fullcalendar.js?

Tags: javascript, date, time, fullcalendar, momentjs

Do these support dates before 1970? How about dates in the 1500s CE? Do these support BCE dates?

I'm curious as well if fullcalendar.js supports other calendars besides gregorian, such as julian, or hebrew or islamic, and whether it supports multiple languages.

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/

Comment: Thanks for the answer on locales/languages - appreciated.

Now what about old or ancient dates, and different calendar systems?

Comment: @dpatte—I would not expect any library based on the built–in Date object to support any calendar other than Gregorian unless there is a simple transformation between the two. It does not make sense to use Gregorian dates before [*October, 1582*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).